# Github pull request "Good to merge"

Tags: github, travis-ci

On Github, I've noticed that some pull requests say that they're "Good to merge" because they have passed a [Travis](http://travis-ci.org) build passed. I have used Travis a little bit, how does it integrate with pull requests on Github?

Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about:

[image: Github good to merge]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Once you've set up Travis and tell it which branch need to be tested, it'll automatically run a build on each pull request targetting one of those branches (and every commit pushed to these branches).

Note that the Travis notification on Github only appears after the build/test is over (roughly 15min).

Comment: So this doesn't require any intervention from the creator of the pull request, it's all done by the owner of the repository?

Comment: Yeah, but Travis manage this automatically once it's installed on your repo. You don't have to do anything manually on each PR

Answer (score 1):

Also, this isn't Travis specific.  Github has an API for continous integration, works for TravisCI, also works with CircleCI.

Answer (score 1):

Note that since December, 8th 2014, you can see *multiple* status from *multiple* services on your pull request.

### See results from all pull request status checks

> Since we introduced the Status API, you've been able to improve the quality of your code by including the status of a pull request within the conversation timeline, for every push.
> **Before today, you've only been able to see results from one service. Now you can see all your results at once, from multiple CI systems that test your code against different platforms to simultaneous security testing and code coverage analysis**.

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/483/5332863/0f58f9b6-7e1a-11e4-9884-e362ec566f2b.png]

> You can also see how the status of a pull request has changed over its history by clicking the icons listed next to individual commits.

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/483/5324992/9caa6820-7c96-11e4-81cc-36bb8287e63d.png]

---

Since July 20th 2015, that status information will be clearly visible in the PR.

See "[Clearer mergability information for Pull Requests](https://github.com/blog/2040-clearer-mergability-information-for-pull-requests)":

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/6104/8488265/6356866a-20df-11e5-8f56-43a55cc04c43.png]

> Each month, 119,000 repositories on GitHub use automated status checks (via the **[GitHub Statuses API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/)**) and it’s important that this information is presented in a way that you can easily understand.
>
> When you’re ready to merge a pull request, you should be able to see that it is ready.
> If a check isn’t passing, you should be able to see why.